# How to add a WM5 target to a WM6 project?

Tags: windows-mobile

My project does not use any WM6-specific APIs, so I want to make it compatible with WM5. However, I see no way of adding another target. I read that it should be as simple as right-clicking on my project and choosing "Change target platform", but the option is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Windows Mobile development, "target" is used mainly for debugging purposes and identifying which emulator or device you want to target for your debug session.

If no specific Windows Mobile 6 APIs are used, your executable should run on a Windows Mobile 5 device without issue.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I also needed to change the configuration in the Configuraiton Manager.